# Why is SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode preferred to HttpUtility.HtmlEncode?

Tags: .net, sputility

The SharePoint Code Analysis Framework [rule SPC020220: Do not call 'HttpUtility.HtmlEncode'](http://docs.spcaf.com/v5/SPC020220_DoNotCallHttpUtilityHtmlEncode.html) states that:

> The assembly should not call `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)` to encode strings [and that] `SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode` [should be used] instead.

I don't understand the rationale. If I understand correctly, both methods perform the same thing. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms445162(v=office.12).aspx):

> The `HtmlEncode` method replaces ampersand, double-quotation, single-quotation, less-than, and greater-than characters with the appropriate entity references.

So does `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)`.

- Why preferring the first to the second?
- What is a case where two methods will perform differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is explained in the link you had given.

> "The .NET Framework HttpUtility encoding library does not encode all
>   characters sufficiently. For example, SPHttpUtility in SharePoint
>   encodes a single quotation mark as ' but .NET Framework HttpUtility
>   does not encode the single quotation mark."

Apart from that, there isn't much preference i guess. 
The `SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode` encodes few other characters that the `HttpUtility` does not encode.